# Is there an easy way to calculate how much you can contribute to an RRSP if you never have before?

Tags: canada, rrsp

Is there a simple way of calculating how much you can contribute to an RRSP if you have never contributed at all?

Comment: Have you ever filed a tax return? Check your resulting Notice of Assesment.

Comment: Thanks. I always got an accountant to do it except last year. I actually do recall the section you mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: don't forget add $2000 to all the answers for the allowed [excess contribution](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/rrsp-reer/cntrbtng/xcss-eng.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally it's about 18% of your lifetime taxable earnings but there is a maximum for each year so this isn't an absolute.

> If you do not have a copy of your notice or a T1028, you can find out the amount of your RRSP deduction limit by going to My Account, Quick Access or by calling our automated TIPS RRSP service. For more information, see My Account and Tax Information Phone Service (TIPS).

[This link](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/t4040/t4040-e.html#P1129_32722) provides how to get it from the gov't or how to calculate it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Calculate, NO.

You can get your available RRSP Contribution amount from last years notice of assessment or by calling the Canadian Revenue Agency.